# windows azure sql server connection error

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, azure

I have  a website with authorization (login page) and I uploaded it to windows Azure. However when I try to login in I have  a network error which says:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

It works fine on local host I think because SQL express is installed. How do I make it work remotely ? `My web.config file` looks like follows:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="none"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you set up a Windows Azure SQL Database and added the connection string for that to your web.release.config file?

Comment: @Mark Rendle I just did that, no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to create new rule in your firewall to allow  SQL remote connection,

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial showing how to configure firewall rules to allow connections:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-create-configure/#configFWLogical

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621782.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure SQL Database comes with a firewall, which by default will stop all IP addresses from accessing the database.

Add a rule to the firewall from the Windows Azure Portal.

More information on this page: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-create-configure/

Comment: I something find that corporate networks block the outbound port for SQL. Could you verify it by connecting SQL Server Management Studio to your SQL Database instance?

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish your local database to the Windows azure. Windows azure will be using SQL server 2008 edition. Have you tried to connect your Windows azure database through Sql server management studio or through Visual Studio. If that connected successfully than this mean that there will be some problem in your connection string. Do one more thing we you try to connect through Visual Studio you will also get the connection string from advanced button. Compare it with your connection string so you will have better idea

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same issue and after long time, I found the solution.

Give the username and password while creating the database as in the following image which you gave while creating mobile service. Server User Name and Server password should be given properly. Don't give your general e-mail ID and Password (which you used to create azure account information) here. It takes some time based on your internet connection. Please be patient till that loads.

[image]